# ui-grid header content menu button overlaps text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, angular-ui-grid

[image]I have noticed that header column menu button is overlapping with the header label, it also happens if you resize the column width

How can this issue be resolved?

```
.ui-grid-column-menu-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Example of this can be seen here as well
http://plnkr.co/edit/29TK44Vor4F45C8hSBNI?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to resolve it with below css

```
.ui-grid-header-cell .ui-grid-cell-contents {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your main.css

```
.ui-grid-column-menu-button-last-col {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

This seems to work.

[Forked Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XnTZAdfGH6zgAtyfjZwB?p=preview)

Uhh, now I see that the **dropdown icon** sometimes overlaps the **sort direction Icon**. So, maybe that's not a good Idea.

But this might help you anyhow ...

Comment: appreciate your help on this, though i have two issues, first one gets resolved with above solution, but second part is when you resize the column. i have added an image to show the issue still happening. basically the dropdown icon i am trying to avoid overlap with text when you resize to decrease with width